# document.title escapes Html, is this standard and solid across all browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, escaping, xss

If I pre-escape my title string `'cats & dogs'` to be set with JavaScript doing `document.title='cats &amp; dogs';` I will get exactly that in the Title, and `'cats &amp;amp; dogs'` in the Html.

So obviously the correct is to pass an *unescaped* string to `document.title`, but I want to be reassured and ask if this is reliable and safe across all Browsers, and no browser would ever set something like `<script>` unescaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [HTML spec for `document.title`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#document.title) says to use [string replace all](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#string-replace-all) when setting the value. This means it creates a Text node and sets the contents as the desired value. Since Text nodes cannot contain HTML, you should be safe in all browsers.